how to fix broken systray menus on ubuntu mate
I'm having sth like this:


The scroll arrows are disabling when I hover cursor over them
Release 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) 64-bit
Kernel Linux 5.15.0-101-generic x86_64
MATE 1.26.0
Running on virtualbox, hosted on win10
any advice?
